# Как определить, является ли url законченным?

Tags: python, url

Как определить, является ли url законченным/ведёт к файлу, а не разделу?

Примеры незаконченных:

```
site.com/a/b
site.com/a/b/c
```

Примеры законченных:

```
site.com/a/doc.html
site.com/a/b/c/doc.pdf
```

Comment: *Примеры незаконченных* С чего бы вот они незаконченные-то? файл как бы не обязан иметь расширения...

Comment: @Akina суть в том, что на сайте есть иерархия файлов как и в файловой системе, так что незаконченный~директория, законченный~недиректория

Comment: Сформулируйте чёткий и совершенно однозначный критерий, позволяющий определить. является путь законченным или нет. текущая формулировка - не подходит.

Comment: @Akina если бы я его знал, то решил бы вопрос уже :)

Comment: Тогда тупо `url.rpartition(".")[2:]` и проверяйте, что в результате нет слэша.

Comment: Файл от директории/раздела невозможно отличить по одному лишь адресу. `site.com/a/b/c` вполне может оказаться файлом.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python - законченый или нет?

Comment: @andreymal он сам сформулировал ТЗ  о законченности :)

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно использовать метод `endswith`:

```
url = 'site.com/a/doc.html'

if url.endswith('.html'):
    print('Законченный')
else:
    print('Незаконченный')
```

UPD:

```
url = 'site.com/a/doc.html'
if '.' in url.split('/')[-1]:
    print('Законченный')
else:
    print('Незаконченный')
```

Comment: Так а если там другой файл? `pdf`, например

Comment: @Bart `endswith(('.html', '.pdf'))`.

Comment: @Bart добавил вариант